# Unable to declare NSManaged variables on the same line in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any change in Swift 2.2 that means the following previously working class file doesn't compile anymore?

```
class Thing {
    @NSManaged private(set) var foo, bar: String?
}
```

Specifically, it seems that the combination of using `NSManaged` and declaring the two variables on a single line cause a compile-time error:

```
1.  While silgen constructor initializer SIL function @_TFC9ParseTest5ThingcfT_S0_ for 'init' at /Users/<...>/Cocoa/ParseTest/ParseTest/Show.swift:23:7
```

This compiles just fine:

```
class Thing {
    @NSManaged private(set) var foo: String?
    @NSManaged private(set) var bar: String?
}
```

Comment: Anything that *crashes* the compiler is a bug. [File a bug](http://bugs.swift.org), if there isn't one already!

Comment: Thanks, I will. I was wondering if there is a reason this isn't supported, and the compiler just fails at telling me what exactly it is. I think it should be valid though.

Comment: Whether it's supported or not is impossible to tell, because the compiler is crashing :)

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1172

Comment: Found an existing report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1050

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the compiler: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1050